# Square modulus question

Tags: modular-arithmetic

"If $p ≡ 1 \pmod 4$ or $q ≡ 1 \pmod 4$,
$p$ is a square $\pmod q$ iff $q$ is a square $\pmod p.$

What does "square mod q" means?

I can't understand this statement.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticReciprocityLaw.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p$ is a square mod $q$ if and only if there is some integer $x$ with $$x^2 \equiv p \; (\bmod q).$$